# Regular Expression Help Needed to Parse Domain Name

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I have a regular expression that returns the top level domain of a URL regardless of whether it is `.com`, `.com.au`, etc. and parses out any subdomains. I need to modify it to return both the top level domain and the first subdomain. So basically if I have for the input

```
http://test1.hello.mydomain.com.au
```

it should return

```
hello.mydomain
```

Can someone help me with this? Here is what I have for grabbing just the top level domain:

```
(?<=^(?:(?:ht|f)tps?)?://)[^/]+?(?=(?:\.(?:[a-z]{2,3}?\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2,3}))(?:/|$))
```

Comment: You have a problem and you want to solve it using regular expressions? Now you have 2 problems :)

Comment: The top level domain in your example: `http://test1.hello.mydomain.com.au` is: `"au"`. If you are asking for the top two levels the answer should be: `"com.au"` and not: `"hello.mydomain"` Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: The expression already deals with whether its .com or .com.au. It works great as far as getting the root domain. But the problem is that it also parses off everything before the root domain and I still want to keep the first subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem that can be solved using regular expressions alone. You are looking for the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/), which contains program-readable information about how to split up domain names in the way you describe.

Comment: Not really... The expression already deals with all the suffixes. I just want to modify it so that it no longer removes the first subdomain. If I give it yes.test.hello.com or yes.test.hello.com.au, etc. it will always return hello. I want it to return test.hello instead. I'm not sure how it does it exactly, but I think it has to do with the length of the domain extension. So it may not be 100% but for my purposes it works well.